# Running AWS Glue crawler on Amazon Redshift logs creates tons of tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have setup audit logs storage from Redshift in S3. Now, I am planning to have external tables setup on these audit logs. On trying to use AWS Glue crawler for reading those files, I get tons of tables. There is one table for each file. I was assuming that there will be two tables overall(as we log two of the activities). If someone has any success in reading Amazon Redshift audit logs using external tables, I would like to have your inputs.

Thanks

Comment: I also saw this blog but it doesn't work the way mentioned in it. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyze-database-audit-logs-for-security-and-compliance-using-amazon-redshift-spectrum/

Comment: There is possibility that either few files are corrupted or schema in few files is changed drastically

Answer (score 0):

Why is the AWS Glue crawler creating multiple tables from my source data, and how can I prevent that from happening? - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/glue-crawler-multiple-tables/